# Unused UDF being called when doing CalculateFullRebuild

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I have some User Defined Functions in an Excel book. I used them for a while but, after a while, I deleted the calls to these functions from the cells because I found a better way to accomplish the same task (I didn't delete the function definition itself in the VBA editor). So, these functions are no longer being called neither in the book nor from any VBA code, I checked it using a search to be 100% sure.

Now I'm doing some review on my code and I noticed something strange: in a Sub procedure in the same workbook (which has nothing to do with these functions) I call `Application.CalculateFullRebuild`. When this happens those UDF get called, I can see it by setting a break point inside the UDF.

I'd like to know why is it happening and what can be done to avoid it, as it is slowing that Sub unnecessarily.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure why the UDF would get called, but you could certainly stop it from happening by removing the dead code that you're not using anymore. (Comment it out if you don't want to lose it.)

Comment: I think part of the answer is that this should not be happening so it's possible you've got something funky going on in the structure of your code. When you hit the breakpoint, you can try viewing your call stack (under the VBA View menu) to give you a clue as to where the call to your function came from

Comment: Add a line `Debug.Print Application.Caller` to your function.  What does it output when you run a full recalculate?

Comment: rename the function, and see what fails?

Comment: I commented out the UDF, which results in slower execution of the Application.CalculateFullRebuild. I imagine not finding the functions becomes slower than calculating them.

Comment: The call stack shows that the function is being called from non VBA code, which is being called in response to Aplication.CalculateFullRebuild.

Comment: I'm gonna try the application.caller to see if it sheds new light. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.CalculateFullRebuild` [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822609%28v=office.15%29.aspx) has this to say:

> The `CalculateFullRebuild` method is similar to re-entering all formulas. ... [When run] a full calculation of the data in all open workbooks is performed and the dependencies are rebuilt.

[Further MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891%28v=office.15%29.aspx) states:

> Causes Excel to rebuild the dependency tree and the calculation chain

This means that any UDFs in the module code or sheet code will be recalculated because Excel is rebuilding and testing functions for dependency and use in the calculation chain.

If you are looking for a way to simply manually calculate the existing formulas in the sheet via your `Sub`, you can use ['Application.Calculate' (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195517%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

```
Application.Calculate 'for all open Sheets
Sheets("Name of Sheet").Calculate 'Specific Sheet
Sheets("Name of Sheet").Range("Name of Range").Calculate 'Specific Range
```

Comment: Thats not correct: unused UDFs will not be called by Application.CalculateFullRebuid because they are not in the depenfdency chain. The dependency chain is built from worksheet formulas not VBA code.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams How is `CalculateFullRebuild` calling the UDFs then?

Comment: The most likely explanation is the UDF is being used in a formula that the OP has not yet found - maybe a hidden sheet or a defined name or a conditional format or a shape or .... Thats why Tim Williams suggestion of using Application.Caller to find out where its being called from is a asensible approach

Answer (score 0):

The system is working as it should.  Consider:

```
Function qwerty() As String
    qwerty = "qwerty"
    MsgBox "XX"
End Function
```

It is non-Volatile and has no arguments.  It will be calculated at the time it is entered in a worksheet cell.  **Application.Calculate** may cause it to be calculated *once,* however:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
End Sub
```

will cause the *UDF* to be re-calculated each time *ytrewq* is run.

Comment: OP states "I deleted the calls to these functions from the cells".  If that is the case (big if) then the system would not be working as it should: a VBA function without any reference from a worksheet (or defined range, conditional formatting, etc) should not be triggered by a calculation.

Comment: To my best knowledge, that is the case. I do not recall using those UDFs neither in contitional formatting nor defined ranges, but I'll check. I will also check for hidden or veryHidden sheets. Any other place where it could be hidden?

Comment: @Jordi  First determine **how** the UDF is being called **MsgBox TypeName(Application.Caller)** within the UDF.  Then look for the *Parent* or the *Address*

Answer (score 0):

To the moment my approach has been commenting all the code inside the UDF with two objectives: increasing speed on one side and checking if any side effect happened on the other side. To the moment, I have not observed any side effect, so more to the point that they are not being used anywhere.

Right now the application I'm developing is working quite well, but I'll try the solutions you're proposing just out of curiosity. By bets are on either it's being used somewhere hidden and forgoten or simply that I have some rubbish inide the workbook structure that is not getting cleaned.

Thanks!

### Update

Tried again the next day and those UDF are no longer being called. Thus, I'll have to assume that something odd was going on with Excel that went away when I restarted it.

Anyway, thanks a lot for the Application.Caller thing, which I didn't know about.